# Why return a function instead of just running that function again (recursion)?

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

If I want to run my function again inside that same function when a certain condition is met, what's the difference between returning that function VS just calling that function again.

```
function myFunc(param) {
  if (param === "3") {
     return myFunc(param);
  }
}
```

VS

```
function myFunc(param) {
  if (param === "3") {
     myFunc(param);
  }
}
```

Comment: You do not return the function, but the result of the function.

Comment: `return` also terminates the function there and then. Without it, code following the function call is still executed.

Comment: In this code, there’s no difference, because there’s nothing that can happen after the `return` and no other value returned. Maybe show a real-world example?

Comment: Both will stack overflow if you pass "3" to it. They are like infinite loops `while(true){}` With tco, reverse the if statement `param !== "3"` and return `myFunc(param)` it would actually be compiled to an infinite loop with the `return` version

Comment: The `return` keyword returns whatever the result of teh follwoing expression. Eg. `return 1+1` will return `2` to the caller. In the bottom every function is an invisible `return undefined`. Note that you can return a fcuntion eg. `return myFunc;` but you are not doing that but return the result of calling the function. Since your base case doesn return anything the result in both cases are `undefiend`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to return a result, then you need to `return` the result of the inner call recursively. For example:

```js
function fact(n) {
  if (n === 0) return 1;
  return n * fact(n - 1);
}
console.log(fact(5));
```

But if the recursive function accomplishes what it needs to *only inside the function* - it's all side-effects from inside - then there's no need to `return`:

```js
function addSpans(container, n) {
  const span = container.appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
  span.textContent = n;
  if (n >= 1) addSpans(span, n - 1);
}
addSpans(document.body, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

`return myFunc()` does three things: (1) execute the function `myFunc()`, (2) when 1 finishes, take the result value and assign it as the return value of the current function, and (3) terminate the current function.

Calling `myFunc()` only does (1). That is the difference.